# Twig multiple variables and json_encode

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

First of all I'm pretty new to Twig.
I'm using a template system so that users can set some options to customize a template. Something similar like Shopify.

I was wondering if it is possible to grab all the settings and send them to javascript function to handle it further.

Let say a user can set these options:

```
{{ theme.hide_label }} // option to show/hide a label
{{ theme.label_color }} // option to set a color for the label
```

I could do something like this and then grab those variables and use them in a js function:

```
 var hideLabel = '{{ theme.hide_label }}'; //true or false
 var labelColor = '{{ theme.label_color }}'; // #000000
```

Unfortunatly I have a lot of settings, so this will be a pretty long list.

I've read about json_encode. But how can I group all those settings/options into something usable for a function?

Something like this:

```
var themeFunctions = {{ theme.label; theme.hidelabel; | t_json | raw }}
```

I've seen somebody did this for translating a lot of text with Twig:

```
var translations = {{ 'Add; Wishlist; Information; Add to wishlist;' | t_json | raw }};
```

And then created a function like so:

```
function getAjaxTranslation(key) {
  var translation;
  if (translation = eval('translations["' + key + '"]')) {
    return translation;
  }
  return key;
}
```

Can something similar be done with variables that are not plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [json_encode](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html) filter with twig.

Data attribute

```
<body data-theme-setting='{{ theme|json_encode|raw }}'>
```

Inside script block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var themeSetting = JSON.parse('{{ theme|json_encode|raw }}');
</script>
```

Hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" id="themeSetting" value='{{ theme|json_encode|raw }}' />
```

If you theme variable is plain object you can encode directly, if not or you want to make white list for variables use [set](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html) and create new variable then encode it.

```
{% set themeSetting = {
    foo : theme.foo,
    label_color : theme.label_color,
    username: theme.user.name
}|json_encode %}
<body data-theme-setting='{{ themeSetting|raw }}'></body>
```

[Example fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/55qtid)

Thanks to [@JoelM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7220351/joel-m), this solution has a weak point with content having single quotes. We need to manually escape the single quotes like below to solve this.

```
{% set themeSetting = {
    foo: "lorem's ipsum dolor's sit",
    label_color : "hello world",
    username: "this text have the ' single quote"
}|json_encode %}
<body data-theme-setting='{{ themeSetting|replace({"'":"\\'"})|raw }}'></body>
```

[Example fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/m4cyyd)

Comment: this did not work for me, it does not escape double quotes.

Comment: @JoelM Correct, in that case, we need to escape the single quotes manually. 
You can check this fiddle for an example https://twigfiddle.com/m4cyyd

Answer (score 0):

why not passing json to the view ?

controlleraction:

```
    public function blaAction(){
       $theme= $themegetter->get('it');

        return array(
          "theme"=>$theme,
          "themejson"=> @json_decode(@json_encode($theme),1)
        )
    }
```

and in js

```
var themejson = {{themejson}}


console.dir(themejson)
console.log(themejson.label);
```